# Convert Wolfram to Python

Tags: list-manipulation, wolfram-cloud, python, findformula

Is there any way for python to generate a list and then find a function based on it just like how FindFit works in Wolfram? Preferably I would like the solution to work on Replit or Google Colab. Thanks :)

Comment: Fitting is a pretty common procedure. Scipy works in colab: [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This is not a question about Mathematica or the Wolfram Language. Unless the post is edited into an on-topic question, it will likely be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Python and not Mathematica.